# Scrollview autoscrolls after changing visibility of Ad

Tags: android, admob, scrollview, visibility

I have a `ScrollView` that contains `Textview`, `Imageview`, `Webview` and a sticky `PublisherAdView` at the bottom of a `RelativeLayout` that contains my `ScrollView` and `PublisherAdView`.

My ad's visibility is `GONE` as default, but after the ad loads, i change the visibility of `PublisherAdView` to `VISIBLE`.

Problem is that when i change the visibility, my `ScrollView` auto scrolls to some location, and i don't want that.

How can i fix this?

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/windowBackground">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view_sticky"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/news_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/resimsiz"/>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#80000000">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/category"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/ad_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_news_detail_sticky"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="WebViewLayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_related_contents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tv_related_contents"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/ad_view_sticky"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_news_detail_sticky"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my code part is

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
PublisherAdView mAdView = (PublisherAdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view_sticky);
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: share the layout and your code please

Comment: try adding android:focusable="false" inside  publisher adview

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to my root `RelativeLayout` solved the problem
Thanks for helps

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do the GONE -> VISIBLE stuff, AdMob SDK handles it for you.

For the undesired scrolling, try to put the ad view outside the scrollview.

Answer (score -1):

Enclose your adView within a `LinearLayout` of fixed height `50dp`. Try the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view_sticky"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@id/ad_view_sticky"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_news_detail_sticky"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

instead of just

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/ad_view_sticky"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_news_detail_sticky"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```